# ServiceStack.Gap for Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Andriod

Tags: xamarin, servicestack

In the spirit of what has already been done with the ServiceStack.Gap project, I'm wondering if it is possible to self-host a ServiceStack service in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Andriod to be consumed by an embedded web client similar to how it was done for Xamarin.Mac.  I haven't seen any success stories regarding this combination and am looking to see if this is even possible before I dive in.

Has anyone had success with this combination?

Comment: It's got a good chance to work with Xamarin.Android which have access to the full Mono framework. It's unlikely the full ServiceStack Framework will work in iOS due to its NoJIT limitations prohibiting many advanced code-gen optimizations.